# Faster/More Efficient Way to call script when Google Form Submit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I need a Google script to run when a user submits a form. I can't use the simple, "add project trigger" from spreadsheet on form submit because there are multiple forms attached to this spreadsheet. My current method to work around this issue is working... most of the time. I'm getting frequent server errors, which I think stems from this extremely inefficient code. 
Does anyone have a suggestion on how to improve this?

```
var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
for(i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++) 
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
var form = FormApp.openById('1tFb-_oaGPRvWpdvXz6nx01rk71m-lLQnM5arjbuz3r4');
ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmails')
 .forForm(form)
 .onFormSubmit()
 .create();
```

EDIT: Thanks for the help. 
Would this fix the problem?

```
var form = FormApp.openById('1Cu14yeOAUYdCST-G8uipGOVPW4qArVcT-7_ElQpmkgE');
var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
if(allTriggers.length<1){ 
   ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmailToTutor')
   .forForm(form)
   .onFormSubmit()
   .create();
} else if(allTriggers.length>1) {
ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[2]);
}
```

This way I only create/delete triggers if I have the wrong amount.

Comment: Error messages generally come with an associated line. You need to include the whole error message. It would appropriately be sensible to include an overview of what your submit script does.

Comment: The errors could be happening from using an Apps Script service many times in rapid succession.  That can cause a quota error.  It doesn't state that it's a quota error.  There is a daily limit to how many triggers you can install.  So, I wouldn't be constantly deleting and re-installing triggers.  The current limitation on trigger creation is 20 / user / script.  [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations)  It is possible to determine what Form made the submission.

Answer (score 2):

You could have one onFormSubmit(event) installed trigger.  In the event object is the range of the cells that are added.  From that range you can get the Sheet that was affected for example "Form Response 1", "Form  Response 2", etc.  Then within the function onFormSubmit(event) have a switch

```
function onFormSubmit(event) {
  switch(event.range.getSheet().getName()) {
    case "Form Response 1":
      // do something
      break;
    case "Form Response 2":
      // do something else
      break;
  }
}
```